# Get literal character from printable character

Tags: parsing

Is it possible to convert a character from printable to literal? (like `"<c-o>"` to `"\<c-o>"`, or `"<F1>"` to `"\<F1>"`), other than by using a dicionary with all special characters. What about the other way around?

My aim to pass a mapping extracted from `:maps` to feedkeys, but feedkeys does not accept non-literal special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
let l:literal = eval('"'.escape('<c-o> <f1> <bar> <ll> \e "', '\<"').'"')
```

When vim encounters `"\<invalid>"` it simply replaces it with `<invalid>`.  A side effect of using double quotes is you need to also escape the characters `\` and `"`, but this is simple to do.

Comment: That's beautiful.